# Relocate style files for metropolis presentation

Tags: beamer, packages, beamer-metropolis

I have adjusted the style files for the metropolis beamer style by adjusting the `beamercolorthememetropolis.sty` file and placed the new file **inside** the main folder of my project.

If I then run the following MWE everything goes fine:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usetheme{metropolis}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{test} test \end{frame}

\end{document}
```

My problem is that this clutters my file management and that I would rather have the new `beamercolorthememetropolis.sty` file in a subfolder. My attempt was:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usetheme{metropolis}

\usepackage{./Preliminaries/beamercolorthememetropolis}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[fragile]{titel} test \end{frame}

\end{document}
```

But this spits out various errors e.g.:

```
LaTeX Warning: You have requested package `./Preliminaries/beamercolorthememetr opolis',
               but the package provides `beamercolorthememetropolis'.

Package: beamercolorthememetropolis 2015/12/04 Metropolis color theme ) (./Preliminaries/beamerinnerthememetropolis.sty

! LaTeX Error: Command \metropolis@inner@setdefaults already defined.
               Or name \end... illegal, see p.192 of the manual.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation. Type  H <return>  for immediate help.  ...                                    

                                                   l.49 }
       Your command was ignored. Type  I <command> <return> to replace it with another command, or  <return>  to continue without it.
```

It would appear that my \usepackage fails to overwrite some settings that are present in the stock version of metropolis if I include them in this fashion...

Comment: If you change something inside a sty file, you need to give it a new name, otherwise you violet tex licence. If the changes are not too substantial I would leave the sty files alone and do the changes within you tex file.

Comment: Ok, I did not know this. (does this count when I do not plan on redistributing them. It's useful to retain the original name so that I retain the original package's structure)

Also, would this fix my problem or is this merely a "style" change ?

Comment: Yes, even if you do not redistribute the code, the original code is still under LPPL. see https://www.latex-project.org/lppl/ for more information

Comment: What did you change in the colour theme? I suspect this can be probably be done from the main file or maybe the changes themself can be placed in a new new color theme.

Comment: If you copy the complete metropolis theme, give it a new name and make your changes in the colour theme and change the names in the theme .sty file, you just have to load `\usetheme{TheFifthElement}` and no extra call for your modified colour theme, so you won't run into the problem you describe above.

Comment: @samcarter, I changed some other files as well. The color theme was just one example to get a MWE.

So, if I understand you correctly you would copy the entire metropolis package + themes in one file and use that as "my" theme ?

Comment: The theme does not have to be in one single file. You can keep the original file structure while copying it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> You cannot modify a latex sty file and keep the same name as this violates LPPL licence.

I see a few alternatives

- use the original metropolis theme and make the changes locally in in your beamer document. For example if you want to change some colour:

  ```
  \documentclass{beamer}

  \usetheme{metropolis}

  \setbeamercolor{frametitle}{fg=red, bg=blue}

  \begin{document}
  \begin{frame}
  \frametitle{test}
  \end{frame}
  \end{document}
  ```
- if the changes are too numerous and clutter you document, you can outsource the changes into a new file, say `./preliminaries/changes.tex` and `\input{./preliminaries/changes.tex}` it into your document
- Or make a copy of the whole `beamertheme-metropolis` folder, rename all files therein which you want to change (remember to also change the package name and the names of the loaded sub-themes in what originally has been called `beamerthememetropolis.sty`). If you prefer to have this new theme in a subfolder, you can adjust the paths to load the theme from a subfolder.